# Uses for an original Le Pan tablet Android 2.2

Tags: updates

2011 Le Pan Android tablet running Froyo.
Before I toss it, are there any practical uses?

Comment: Bedside clock /alarm?

Comment: That's what my old Moto does (bedside alarm), thanks to the nice docking station it got :) Other use cases could be (always provided there are still "froyo apps" available where needed): desk calendar, web cam, security cam, digital photo frame – [this article](https://www.computerworld.com/article/2487680/20-great-uses-for-an-old-android-device.html) lists 20 uses.